# The essential pre-processing steps in speech signal analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, speech-processing, speech-recognition, preprocessing

My question is that for simulating a new scheme for speech emotion recognition (feature extraction and classification), what are the necessary pre-processing steps (I mean any kind of normalization and etc. on a EMODB database)?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "simulate an algorithm": what does that mean? Do you mean you want to write another algorithm that does the same as the original one? Why not simply use the original one? And: pre-processing depends on what kind of data you have at hand, so without a lot more info, no answer that isn't overly generic can be given.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: this is a feature extraction scheme. I edited the question.